# Fading in and out text in block

Tags: javascript, html, css, fade

I have a block which content is being dynamically changed by script and I want that content not to change instantly, but fade out and then fade in with new content.
I want that done without jQuery — pure JS and CSS.
I am trying to do this in such a way:
I've defined transparent and opacle classes in CSS with transition set to 2s, and wanna toggle that classes for block with content when the content changes. As I expect it should smoothly fade out old content and fade in new content. But in fact content just changes instantly.
CSS:

```
.non-opacle {
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
.opacle {
    opacity:1;
    transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
```

HTML

```
       <div class="alert alert-info" id="wrapper">
            <p id="text-box">…</p>
        </div>
```

JS

```
var textBox = document.getElementById('text-box');
window.onload = function () {
    var failCounter = 0;
    var current = notes[Math.floor(Math.random() * 12)];
    textBox.className = 'opacle';
    textBox.innerHTML = '…';
    function keyClicked(event) {
        if (event.target.className.split(' ')[1] === current) {
            textBox.className = 'non-opacle';
            textBox.innerHTML = '*some altered content*';
            textBox.className = 'opacle';
    …
```

In JS I initially set content wrapper block to 'opacle' class with initial content, and then on certain conditions, I set it to 'non-opacle', change block's innerHTML to place relevant content, and set the class back to 'opacle'.
But no animation occurs( What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please include a sample of your HTML & JS in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're adding and removing the `opacity` at the same time, before the initial transition has had time to complete.

What you need to do is delay the changing of the `innerHTML` and resetting of the `opacity` until the transition has completed.

Here's a very simple looping example to illustrate the principle, the important part to note is the `setTimeout`.

```js
var p=document.getElementById("change"),text=["One","Two","Three","Four","Five"],x=0,interval=setInterval(function(){
    x++;if(x===text.length)x=0;
    p.classList.add("hide");
    setTimeout(function(){
        p.innerHTML=text[x];
        p.classList.remove("hide");
    },500);
},2000);
```

```css
#change{
    color:#000;
    font-family:arial;
    padding:5px;
    transition:opacity .5s linear;
}
.hide{
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<p id="change">One</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The browser is not going to wait for transitions to complete before setting the class back to opacle.

This simple working fiddle moves the transition out to a separate selector, and uses [a transitionend event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions#Detecting_the_completion_of_a_transition), to wait for the element to be completely faded out before changing the content and fading it back in.

http://jsfiddle.net/0m3Lpwxo/1/

CSS:

```
.opacle {
    opacity:1;
}

.non-opacle {
    opacity:0;
}

#test {
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="test" class="non-opacle">this is content</div>
<button onclick="toggle()">toggle</button>
```

js:

```
function transitionEnded() {
    var el = document.getElementById('test');
    el.innerHTML = "hello.";
    el.classList.remove('non-opacle');
}

function toggle() {
    var el = document.getElementById('test');
    el.addEventListener("transitionend", transitionEnded, true);
    el.classList.add('non-opacle');
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a few hours for a solution to transition an other element after clicking a button. By far the most easy and straight forward solution!

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to define browser specific styles along side your current definition (for example: -webkit-transition: opacity 2s linear;)

Also, I would say that instead of adding the transition redundantly to both classes, target something about your element that's not going to change, like its ID and define the transition style rules there. That way you will keep your CSS more DRY.

Here's the best reference material for dealing with CSS transitions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: Have you tested what you're proposing to see if it fixes the problem being presented in the question?

Comment: I answered at a time before the OP edited his question to provide more information, and at the time there wasn't enough context to test in a meaningful/relevant way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="myElement">Text</div>

function fadeOut(id,val){
  if(isNaN(val)){ val = 9;}
  document.getElementById(id).style.opacity='0.'+val;
  //For IE
  document.getElementById(id).style.filter='alpha(opacity='+val+'0)';
  if(val>0){
    val--;
    setTimeout('fadeOut("'+id+'",'+val+')',90);
  }else{return;}
}

function fadeIn(id,val){
  if(isNaN(val)){ val = 0;}
  document.getElementById(id).style.opacity='0.'+val;
  //For IE
  document.getElementById(id).style.filter='alpha(opacity='+val+'0)';

  if(val<9){
    val++;
    setTimeout('fadeIn("'+id+'",'+val+')',90);
   }else{return;}
}
```

Referred from [this](http://www.claindsilva.com/javascript/how-to-cross-fade-anything-with-javascript-javascript-fade-effect/).

Comment: Yep, I think about fading it with function, but I'm currently trying to do this with transition and can't stay calm until I find out why it won't work

Answer (score 0):

I have used following `JS`:

```
function change(){
    var d = document.getElementById("div");
    d.className = d.className + " non-opacle";
    setTimeout(function(){
       d.className = "opacle";
        d.innerHTML = "TEST";
    },1000);
}
```

See following [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hs8ojsfb/1/), with `CSS`:

```
.opacle {
    opacity:1;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
.non-opacle {
    opacity:0;/* No need to add transaction here */
}
```